# Migrate wiki pages to Enterprise wiki OOB

Tags: 2010, migration, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

Is it somehow possible to migrate wiki pages (Wiki Library) to Enterprise Wiki Site with OOB capabilities?
Or, in other words, to migrate the content of wiki pages (Wiki Library) to Enterprise Wiki Page (Site) without directly touching SQL or writting code (however, using powershell cmdlets would be plausible).

Version of SharePoint is 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the move is between same server**

1. Activate the site collection feature SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure.
2. Go to the Site Settings page of the desired site which the Wiki Page libraries locate on, Click on Content and structure shows up under Site Administration.
3. Select the page and use content menu to move the page to another library

**Different Server**

1. Save the page library as template using 'Library Settings' page
2. Upload the stp file to target server
3. Create a new temporary library using the new template. Then use above approach to move pages to the actual destination library

Comment: While this works, problem is - wiki pages keep their layout which was one of the reasons to migrate to Enterprise Wiki